# SSIS Multicast Issue: Weird behavior

Tags: ssis, multicast, undefined-behavior

I am working on Integration services and came across a weird bug.

My data flow consist of:

```
                                         -> DESTINATION
SOURCE -> SCRIPT_COMPONENT -> MULTICAST /
                                        \-> DESTINATION
```

This error always occurs but differs the columns that is being addressed:

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at *STAFF_MIGRATION*, *STAFF_BASE* [627]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
Error: 0xC020901C at *STAFF_MIGRATION*, *STAFF_BASE* [627]: There was an error with input column "*LAST_UPDATED_BY*" (651) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (640). The column status returned was: "The status value given to the provider was not valid.".
```

The column `LAST_UPDATED_BY` differs to sometimes `LAST_UPDATE_DATE`

The weird behaviour is that this doesnt occur if I add Data Viewers along the path to the destination.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am running on VS/BIDS 2008 SPI and SQL Server 2008 (RTM) x64 SP1.

EDIT: I am now running on SQL Server SP3 and still the behavior occurs.

Comment: `LAST_UPDATED_BY` and `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` in what data type columns you are writing.

Comment: they are written to the same data types. GUID and datetimestamp respectively. They work fine if I add the data viewers on the paths. I don't really get why that happens

Comment: Can you try to capture more logging, using a Log Manager, rather than just the output. Also, does this _always_ occur when run without the data viewers or just some of the time?

Comment: Always.. I think my theory could be right. When I place a data viewer, it means it needs to build the data set for me to view prior to insertion. So the values for the columns must be built. I found a solution by making the destination a fast load table where bulk insertion is intended. That would mean it would have time to build the data and would not encounter the invalid value for columns.. It was just a wild guess but it worked

Comment: Never experienced such a problem, strange. Move your comment in Answer and mark it as right.

Comment: GUIDs and time stamps are by definition system generated.  Why would you obsess over what exact values they contain?  If you need control over what goes into those fields then you should consider other datatypes.

Comment: I actually have a constant GUID for the admin and added it in a script component and i need a consistent timestamp because i am migrating data from an old database schema to a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my theory could be right. When I place a data viewer, it means it needs to build the data set for me to view prior to insertion. So the values for the columns must be built. I found a solution by making the destination a fast load table where bulk insertion is intended. That would mean it would have time to build the data and would not encounter the invalid value for columns.. It was just a wild guess but it worked